# Use NSArray to Populate Different UIImages?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, uiimageview

I've seen tutorials online of using an array to create animations within a specific UIImageView. What I'm trying to do is a little bit different, and I'm not quite sure how to go about it.

I have ten different UIImageViews on my storyboard. I have an array of 10 different elements. What I'd like to do is populate the UIImageViews at random with my array. So the first time you load the upper right hand ImageView would have Image A, and then the next time you load it would have Image B.

I've created a method called randomNumber to pull a random number from the array count at random. But I'm not quite sure where to go from here. Any pointers? Thank you!

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    kana = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"a.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"i.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"u.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"e.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"o.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"ka.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"ki.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"ku.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"ke.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"ko.png"],
                        nil];


[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

-(id) randomNumber
{
    if ([kana count] > 0)
    {
      id obj = kana[arc4random_uniform([kana count])];
      return obj;
    }
    else
      return nil;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you don't want duplicates, so you iterate over the image views and, on each iteration, you get a random image from `kana` and then remove that image from the array. So long as you have at least as many images as you have image views everything works well.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, but I'm still not sure how that would work. How would I iterate over each of the image views? I'm still foggy on how I can assign the obj to an Image View... would it be something like UIImage *Monster1 = [kana objectAtIndex:obj]?

Comment: You would use your (badly named, because it returns a random image, not a number) `randomNumber` method to get the image. Look at using IBOutletCollection to manage your list of image views.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am very new to this so I'm not really following. How can I use my method to get the image, when the method returns an obj? I can't use objectAtIndex, since that requires an int. And isn't a Collection only good when I'm using the same image for multiple ImageViews?

Comment: Would this work do you think? CGFloat myFloat = [(NSNumber*)[self randomNumber] floatValue];

Comment: No, the method returns an image (which is perfect). [currentImageView setImage:[self randomNmber]];

Comment: The array contains images, and the method should return an image (not id).

Comment: The program doesn't seem to recognize [currentImageView setImage:[self randomNumber]];. I did try the following: int imageDisplay = arc4random_uniform([kana count]);
    
    Monster1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[kana objectAtIndex:imageDisplay]]; but it triggered my ending method for some reason.

Comment: Ending method? That code looks generally correct (except that you create a new image view instead of accessing one from the storyboard)

Comment: My ImageView on the storyboard is called Monster1. Is using initWithImage not the correct way to load an image into an image view? The ending method is pretty simple, it just triggers a label display whenever the frame of Monster1 intersects with the frame of another imageView.

Comment: No, `alloc` creates a new instance and `init...` configures it. You said you had multiple image views, so an IBOutletCollection is best, but: `[self.monster1 setImage:[kana objectAtIndex:imageDisplay]];`